# iOS Swift avplayer previous or next button

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I Have an Array with songobjects. I use avplayer to play those .mp3 files.
How can I use the buttons to play the next song or the previous song?
I can stop the song or going back and choose another one, but I cant manually switch the songs when playing.

```
func playSong(url: NSURL){

let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

 playerController.player = AVPlayer(URL: url.absoluteURL)


NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MusicListViewController.playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)),
                                                 name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerController.player!.currentItem)

self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

playerController.player?.play();   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AVPlayer` you should use `AVQueuePlayer`.

Code would look like this, where you could add all of your `AVPlayerItem` objects:

```
let item1 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "1")!)
let item2 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "2")!)
let item3 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "3")!)

let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [item1, item2, item3])
```

After you've done this, just add the player to `AVPlayerViewController` as usual.